# spring boot drools ConstraintEvaluationException with multiple drl files

Tags: spring-boot, drools, kie

spring boot 2.x, `kie-ci 7.59.0.Final`

```
package com.collyer.rest.config;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.*;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class DroolsConfig {

    private static final String RULES_PATH = "rule/";

    @Bean
    public KieFileSystem kieFileSystem() throws IOException {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = getKieServices().newKieFileSystem();
        for (Resource file : getRuleFiles()) {
            kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(RULES_PATH + file.getFilename(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return kieFileSystem;
    }

    private Resource[] getRuleFiles() throws IOException {
        ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        return resourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath*:" + RULES_PATH + "**/*.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() throws IOException {
        final KieRepository kieRepository = getKieServices().getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
            public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
                return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
            }
        });
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = getKieServices().newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem());
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        return getKieServices().newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
    }

    private KieServices getKieServices() {
        return KieServices.Factory.get();
    }
}
```

I have one `d.drl` file under the `src/main/resources/rule`, it looks like:

```
package com.my.rest.service;
//set import and global

rule "groupA_A_0"
    agenda-group "groupA"
    activation-group "groupA_A"
    when        
        $j : JSONObject(aSize == 1)
    then
        System.out.println("####A-0");
        ....
end
```

the code to fire is:

```
@Autowired
private KieContainer kieContainer;

public testA() {
KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
//...set global
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("aSize", 1);
kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("groupA").setFocus();
kSession.insert(json);
kSession.fireAllRules();
}
```

it works fine.

However, if I add another `a.drl` whose is

```
package com.my.rest.service;
//set import and global

rule "groupB_A_0"
    agenda-group "groupB"
    activation-group "groupB_A"
    when        
        $j : JSONObject(bSize == 1)
    then
        System.out.println("####A-0");
        ....
end
```

the corresponding code to fire is:

```
public testB() {
KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
//...set global
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("bSize", 2);
kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("groupB").setFocus();
kSession.insert(json);
kSession.fireAllRules();
}
```

the error thrown when executing `testB()` which is used to fire rules of `a.drl`:
`org.drools.mvel.ConstraintEvaluationException: Error evaluating constraint 'aSize == 1' in [Rule "groupA_A_0" in rule/d.drl]`

`JSONObject` is `net.sf.json.JSONObject`(like a Map), `aSize` is put into `JSONObject` when fire rules of `d.drl` while `bSize` is put when fire rules of `a.drl`.

i just want to fire rules of `a.drl`, why it said the error of `d.drl`?(and at this time, fire rules of `d.drl` is successed)

how to fix it?

Comment: Agenda group is a rule attribute. You've got the `agenda-group` declaration outside of any rule, just kind of floating in mid file. And before you try arguing with me that "the documentation is wrong, all the rules should inherit it" ... well if that's the case, wouldn't all the rules _in the same package_ inherit it?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks for your comment. I tried move the `agenda-group` to the rule for both `.drl` files, but still got the same error.